# How do download a file with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, plist, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am having a hard time sifting through search results for how to do this and I can't find anything concrete in the documentation. I just want to download a file and store in the Documents directory. The file is of type .plist, but I don't need to parse the plist. Like I said I just need to save it to disk.

Do I use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager for this?

This is what I've been trying in general:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    //manager.responseSerializer = [AFPropertyListResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             DLog(@"downloaded plist");
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             DLog(@"JSON DataError: %@", error);
         }];
```

If I use AFHTTPResponseSerializer I get this:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)"
```

If I use AFPropertyListResponseSerializer I get this:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain"
```

But I'm not even sure I'm using the correct API.

Comment: (This) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372661/how-to-download-a-file-and-save-it-to-the-documents-directory-with-afnetworking] might help.

Comment: That uses the old version of AFNetworking though. Is that still the recommended way?

Comment: Tried that and I still get Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)

Comment: Recommended way for downloading files with AFNetworking 2.0 - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-a-download-task

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295696/download-file-using-afnetworking-on-ios-6

Answer (score 15):

Please, try this example.
Hope this help!

```
// Step 1: create NSURL with full path to downloading file
// for example try this: NSString *fileUrl = @"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2331579964/jrqzn4q29vwy4mors75s_400x400.png";
// And create NSURLRequest object with our URL
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

// Step 2: save downloading file's name
// For example our fileName string is equal to 'jrqzn4q29vwy4mors75s_400x400.png'
NSString *fileName = [URL lastPathComponent];

// Step 3: create AFHTTPRequestOperation object with our request
AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Step 4: set handling for answer from server and errors with request
[downloadRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // here we must create NSData object with received data...
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:responseObject];
            // ... and save this object as file
            // Here 'pathToFile' must be path to directory 'Documents' on your device + filename, of course
            [data writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"file downloading error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

// Step 5: begin asynchronous download
[downloadRequest start];
```

Something else: [What's the best way to find the user's Documents directory on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone)

Comment: Write some explanation tooo.

Comment: Sorry for my bad style in answers :)
Now this better?

Comment: can u please tell me what if same request will execute multiple time?can we check before starting the download that if there is already running the process for same request?

Comment: Good question! But, sorry, I don't know answer for this question.
But I think you can check exists or not exists file at 'pathToFile'

Comment: @BhavikKama, why can't we add next request to a queue and set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` ?

Comment: how to call Get type method and pass some header data to download a file