# Show progress for downloading image using AFNetworkig

Tags: ios, afnetworking, progress, download

I wanted to show progress when downloading a large image. I am 
setting the image path as follows.

```
UIImage *backgroundImage =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:backgoundImagePath]]];
```

How can i show the download progress of the image using AFNetworking framework.

Comment: tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145093/how-to-get-download-progress-in-afnetworking-2-0 ?

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
[manager setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
float percentageDone = ((float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)*100;
      NSLog(@"Downloading..%.f",percentageDone);   
}];
```