# How to create UIProgressViewStyleBar on UIAlertview iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, user-interface

I am trying to create `UIProgressViewStyleBar on UIAlertview` with `JSON` loading status info on my app. Now my problem is I cant see `UIProgressViewStylebar on iOS 7`. Please help me!

My Source:

```
UIAlertView *alertss = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait..Downloading reports..."    message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
alertss.frame=CGRectMake(50, 50, 280, 40);
UIProgressView *prgView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
prgView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 70, 20);
prgView.hidden=NO;
[alertss addSubview:prgView];
[alertss show];
UILabel *statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
statusLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Condensed" size:18.0];
statusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 80, 80, 20);
[alertss addSubview:statusLabel];
[alertss show];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Running"     message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   UIProgressView* progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 15);
progressView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 15);
progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[progressView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[progressView setTrackTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[progressView setProgressTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 [progressView setProgress:0.75f animated:YES];
// you have to set the accessoryView to alertview
[av setValue:progressView forKey:@"accessoryView"];

[av show];
```

Comment: Try this above code  i hope it will help you.if you adding any subview to alertview you have to add the accessoryView to alertview

Comment: Thanks. But its showing completed one. I need to show real time loading like percentage with some JSON status info.Please post some sample code @kamalkumar

Comment: i have updated the code.do you get json response by using afnetworking

Comment: check this you have answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145093/how-to-get-download-progress-in-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: how to add Progresshud on alert view

Comment: check this link https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD and download the  libary file from that link and add to your project

Comment: I already did everything.  what i am asking how to add ProgressStyleBar on UIAlertView from MBProgressHud@Kamal

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is the correct code with that code add this line

```
 [progressView setProgress:0.75f animated:YES];
```

before showing your alert. change the progress value depends on your need. or animate it if you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am asking How to show percentages or some status informations same time dats red line should move based on JSON loading!@deepakraj

Comment: ya for that you need to add animation to the progressview so that red line will move automatically with respect to your feed

Comment: If you dont mind give some sample. I am new for ios!@deepak

Comment: ya will give you dont worry. but my question was why dont you try this progress hud library named as MBProgressHUD.

Comment: I dont know how to integrate that. Looks above very easy for me

Answer (score 0):

see adding MBprogressHUD is so simple. first download the MBProgressHUD Lib from the [GitHub](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and import in your project as `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"`

And then simple line to show the progressHUD is as follows :

to show:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

to hide:

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

for your problem use this code:

```
  av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Running" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        [av show];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Here I used the circular loader. if you want to customise it you can use this loader in many forms as you wish.

Comment: see its not helping me nothing. I said I am new for ios!