# CAShapeLayer path animation has serious delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, cashapelayer

I'm attempting to create a loading screen that draws a circle while my app makes network requests. The amount drawn of the circle is meant to represent how close the request is to finishing. However there is a serious delay (~8 seconds) between the network request and the animation. After A LOT of searching I haven't found anyone that has had this problem before so I'm very desperate.

My setup right now is that an NSProgress object will be updated as a request is being made and will trigger a KVO Notification with the NSProgress object in the userInfo. This is the same method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380812/2589965).

```
#Client.m
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"] && [object isKindOfClass:[NSProgress class]]) {
        NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"progress":progress};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FractionCompleted" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Then the view controller that is listening for the notification will update the LoadingProgressView with the fractionCompleted of the NSProgress object that it receives.

```
#MainViewController.m
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) name:@"FractionCompleted" object:nil];
...
...
- (void)updateProgress:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSProgress* prog = note.userInfo[@"progress"];
    [self.progressIndicatorView updateProgress:(CGFloat)prog.fractionCompleted];
}
```

Now within the LoadingProgressView, the CAShapeLayer's strokeEnd property is set as the fractionCompleted value. I am using the same idea from the tutorial found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94302/implement-circular-image-loader-animation-cashapelayer).

```
#LoadingProgressView.m
- (void)updateProgress:(CGFloat)frac {
    _circlePathLayer.strokeEnd = frac;
}
```

When I actually make a request, nothing happens until about 5 seconds AFTER the request is finished. At that point the entire circle is animated at once.

I have ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA why this is happening and it's driving me crazy. I can clearly see using the debugger that the strokeEnd property is being updated in real-time and yet the LoadingProgressView refuses to re-render until much later. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: OK so a temporary solution was to fork a new thread with a delay of 0 to update the progress view for each notification. However this seems like poor thread management since I could be creating over a hundred different threads to do the same task. I'm wondering if there's anything else I can do.

```
- (void)updateProgress:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSProgress* prog = note.userInfo[@"progress"];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progressIndicatorView updateProgress:(CGFloat)prog.fractionCompleted];
    });
}
```

Comment: `dispatch_after` doesn't create (or `fork`) a new thread - it just runs a block on a specified queue. Passing `dispatch_get_main_queue()` will effectively run this block on the main thread.

Comment: Also, updating the UI outside from main thread is not gonna work :)

Comment: Haha oh ok thanks for the info. Would you mind explaining what's going on here and why I had to do this in the first place?

Comment: Call `setNeedsDisplay` after stroke

Comment: @anhtu the problem still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. It seems to be caused by setting the path from a background thread. Ensuring this happens on the main thread solved the problem. Now updating the shape draws immediately.

Comment: Though this answer appears to be correct, or at least on the right track, could you provide more information and some code to clarify?

Comment: @s1m0nw1: this is not a different question